Limit and Colimit over Yoneda Functor
The Question
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category. Then we can consider the Yoneda functor
$$
\newcommand{\op}[1]{{#1}^{\operatorname{op}}}
y: \mathcal{C} \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Fun}(\op{\mathcal{C}}, \mathsf{Set}), \\
c \mapsto y_c, \\
y_c: d \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(d, c)
$$
I want to calculate the following two things:

The limit over the Yoneda functor
$$
\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_c \in \operatorname{Fun}(\op{\mathcal{C}}, \mathsf{Set}),
$$

The colimit over the Yoneda functor
$$
\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c \in \operatorname{Fun}(\op{\mathcal{C}}, \mathsf{Set}),
$$


Since $\mathsf{Set}$ is complete and cocomplete, limits and colimits in functor categories are computed pointwise and $\mathcal{C}$ is small, these always exist.
The Case of an Initial or Terminal Object
In the case that $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object $i$, the answer to question (1) is easy: The limit is simply given by evaluation at $i$, i.e.
$$
\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_c = y_i
$$
and hence
$$
\left( \underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_c \right)(d) = y_i(d) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(d, i)
$$
For example, for $\mathcal{C} = \mathsf{FinSet}$ (which is essentially small), we have that the initial object is $\emptyset$, so that
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{FinSet}}(d, \emptyset) = \begin{cases} \{\ast\} & d \cong \emptyset \\ \emptyset & \text{otherwise} \\ \end{cases}
$$
So, in this case, we have
$$
\left( \underset{c \in \mathsf{FinSet}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_c \right)(d) = \begin{cases} \{\ast\} & d \cong \emptyset \\ \emptyset & \text{otherwise} \\ \end{cases}
$$
Analogously, in the case that $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object $t$, the answer to question (2) is easy: The colimit is simply given by evaluation at $t$, i.e.
$$
\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c = y_t
$$
and hence
$$
\left( \underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c \right)(d) = y_t(d) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(d, t) = \{\ast\}
$$
So, in this case, we have
$$
\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c = \operatorname{const}_{\{\ast\}}
$$
A Simplification with the Yoneda Lemma
For concreteness, $\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_c$ consists of some $F \in \operatorname{Fun}(\op{\mathcal{C}}, \mathsf{Set})$ together with natural transformations $\eta_c: F \to y_c$ such that for $f: c \to c'$, we have $\eta_{c'} = [f \circ -] \circ \eta_c$, i.e. the following diagram commutes:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
& \eta_c & y_c & \\
& \nearrow & & \\
F & & \downarrow & [f \circ -] \\
& \searrow & & \\
& \eta_{c'} & y_{c'} & \\
\end{array}
$$
$\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_c$ should now be the terminal such $F$.
On the other hand, $\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c$ consists of some $F \in \operatorname{Fun}(\op{\mathcal{C}}, \mathsf{Set})$ together with natural transformations $\eta_c: y_c \to F$ such that for $f: c \to c'$, we have $\eta_c = \eta_{c'} \circ [f \circ -]$, i.e. the following diagram commutes:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
& y_c & \eta_c & \\
& & \searrow & \\
[f \circ -] & \downarrow & & F \\
& & \nearrow & \\
& y_{c'} & \eta_{c'} & \\
\end{array}
$$
However, due to the Yoneda Lemma, this can be described more directly: $\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c$ consists of some $F \in \operatorname{Fun}(\op{\mathcal{C}}, \mathsf{Set})$ together with elements $x_c \in F(c)$ such that for $f: c \to c'$, we have $F(f)(x_{c'}) = x_c$. $\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c$ should now be the initial such $F$.
A concrete Example
Finally, let's compute both of these things in an explicit example without an initial/terminal object.
To this end, consider the following $\mathcal{C}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & f_2 & \bullet & c_2 \\
& & \nearrow & & \\
c_1 & \bullet & & & \\
& & \searrow & & \\
& & f_3 & \bullet & c_3 \\
\end{array}
$$
We also have $\op{\mathcal{C}}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
& & \op{f_2} & \bullet & \op{c_2} \\
& & \swarrow & & \\
\op{c_1} & \bullet & & & \\
& & \nwarrow & & \\
& & \op{f_3} & \bullet & \op{c_3} \\
\end{array}
$$
$\mathcal{C}$ has no terminal object. We will now compute $\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c$. We obtain the following functors:
$y_{c_1}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \emptyset \\
& \swarrow & \\
\{\ast\} & & \\
& \nwarrow & \\
& & \emptyset \\
\end{array}
$$
$y_{c_2}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \{\ast\} \\
& \swarrow & \\
\{\ast\} & & \\
& \nwarrow & \\
& & \emptyset \\
\end{array}
$$
$y_{c_3}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \emptyset \\
& \swarrow & \\
\{\ast\} & & \\
& \nwarrow & \\
& & \{\ast\} \\
\end{array}
$$
And hence we can now compute $\underset{c \in \mathcal{C}}{\operatorname{colim}} y_c$, which is the pointwise pushout of the above diagrams:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \{\ast\} \\
& \swarrow & \\
\{\ast\} & & \\
& \nwarrow & \\
& & \{\ast\} \\
\end{array}
$$
Analogously, $\op{\mathcal{C}}$ has no initial object. We will now compute $\underset{\op{c} \in \op{\mathcal{C}}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_{\op{c}}$. We obtain the following functors:
$y_{\op{c_1}}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \{\ast\} \\
& \nearrow & \\
\{\ast\} & & \\
& \searrow & \\
& & \{\ast\} \\
\end{array}
$$
$y_{\op{c_2}}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \{\ast\} \\
& \nearrow & \\
\emptyset & & \\
& \searrow & \\
& & \emptyset \\
\end{array}
$$
$y_{\op{c_3}}$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \emptyset \\
& \nearrow & \\
\emptyset & & \\
& \searrow & \\
& & \{\ast\} \\
\end{array}
$$
And hence we can now compute $\underset{\op{c} \in \op{\mathcal{C}}}{\operatorname{lim}} y_{\op{c}}$, which is the pointwise pullback of the above diagrams:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & \emptyset \\
& \nearrow & \\
\emptyset & & \\
& \searrow & \\
& & \emptyset \\
\end{array}
$$

For the colimit, it's not too hard to check that $\mathrm{const}\ {*}$ always works.

@NaimFavier Can you elaborate a little more? It's clear to me that this gives a cocone, but why is it the initial such thing?

As I said it's not hard to check, so you should check it. Here's an Agda proof.

@NaimFavier Ah, I think I get it now. The unique morphism from $\operatorname{const}_{{\ast}}$ to $(F, (x_c)_c)$ just sends $\ast$ to $x_c$. This is clearly unique (this is already determined by the morphism condition for cocones), and by the compatibility condition on the $x_c$, this is actually a natural map. Thank you, I don't know how I didn't see that before.

It's the Yoneda lemma in disguise, by the way.

Limits in $\textbf{Set}$ can be described as sets of cones.
The same applies here: the component of $\varprojlim_c y_c$ at $d$ is $\varprojlim_c \mathcal{C} (d, c)$, which is the set of cones over the diagram $\textrm{id} : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ with vertex $d$.
In the case where $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object $i$, as you say, $\varprojlim_c y_c$ is a represented by $i$.
As mentioned in the comments, $\varinjlim_c y_c \cong 1$ always.
Here is a quick derivation:
$$[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] ( \varinjlim_c y_c, F ) \cong \varprojlim_c {[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]} (y_c, F) \cong \varprojlim_c F (c) \cong [\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] (1, F)$$
We use the Yoneda lemma in its "official" form ${[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]} (y_c, F) \cong F (c)$ and also its well known corollary to deduce from $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] ( \varinjlim_c y_c, F ) \cong [\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] (1, F)$ that $\varinjlim_c y_c \cong 1$.
The natural bijection $\varprojlim_c F (c) \cong [\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}] (1, F)$ is precisely the identification of limits in $\textbf{Set}$ with cones I mentioned above.

"the component of $\varprojlim_c y_c$ at $d$ is $\varprojlim_c \mathcal{C} (d, c)$, which is the set of cones over the diagram $\textrm{id} : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ with vertex $d$." Is there an even more explicit description of this?

An element of this set consists of morphisms $d \to c$ for all $c$, compatible with respect to morphisms in $c$. I am afraid for general categories we cannot simplify this. But I assume when you actually restrict to a specific category this set will often be trivial in some sense (well unless an initial object exists, in which case $d \to i$ is enough). You may also want to look at the path category of a graph as an example.
